# Is there a Tool for monitoring websites for new created Images and subdomains, instead of keywords and page contents?

Tags: url, google-chrome-extension, directory, monitoring

First of all, I have zero knowledge about coding, programming etc. Its a different World:)
Because of this, sorry if I'm not using coding/programming terms and also sorry for my poor english.

I'm looking for a simple tool software/browser extension to monitor websites for new created Files (jpg, png, pdf) and to monitor new created subdomains and new API (.json) pages. 
I should just enter the directory URL's of the websites i want to monitor, like this maybe:

JPG: https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/*********.jpg

PNG: https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/global.semi.static/*********.png

PDF: https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/global.semi.static/*********.pdf

SUBDOMAIN: https://sports.yahoo.com/nba/teams/*******

API PAGE: www.istream.com/api/ws/row/tv/channel/clips/*********.json (or without .json)

...that's it.

Finally, it should alert me immediately via deskop notification or E-mail.

Comment: It's not really possible to "subscribe" to these kind of events, as I see mapping new URLs can be done in two ways, with a web crawler (only works for URLs that are publicly linked somewhere) or by trial/error (very expensive since it has to request all possible entries and retry that over and over again).
Perhaps you could use a complex google search query to find recently added URLs that are publicly linked to. I don't think there is a kind of service that you are looking for.

Comment: I agree with @GergelySzabo, however, to throw just another method out there, you may be able to do something like, download the entire html, and compare it with one you downloaded at an earlier time...

As far as a tool existing, I don't know of, but you should build it...